# Duplicated sections and odd behaviour

Tags: bug, ios-app, ios-app-feed

It appears the app duplicated a section of questions.

Also when swiping right on the first of the duplicates the icon on the second changes and not the first.

**Duplicated Questions**
[image: duplicate]

**First section swiped, second section icon changed.**
[image: odd behaviour]